# How to use PyPy (for python 3.6) on PyCharm running on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pycharm, pypy

Hi I'm trying to use PyPy (for Python 3) as an interpreter on my PyCharm community version running on Windows 10. I don't see any install options specifically for Windows on the PyPy website.

Is there a way to use the source code or the binaries to use PyPy on my Pycharm?

Answer (score 8):

The 32-Bit Beta Version for Windows works. In detail:

- Tested today 2. July 2018
- 2018-06 Windows 10 Version 1803 for Intel based systems (KB4284848)
- pypy3-v6.0.0-win32.zip downloaded today from http://pypy.org/download.html
- PyCharm 2018.1.4 Professional Edition

I've unpacked the downloaded "pypy3-v6.0.0-win32.zip" to "C:\pypy3-v6.0.0-win32". No need to run any installer. I've created a new PyCharm-Project. Go to into the Menu "File" select "Settings". Then select "Project pane", click the Cog, click "Add ...", click "System Interpreter", click "..." on the top-right and navigate to "C:\pypy3-v6.0.0-win32\pypy3.exe".

PyCharm took a while to generate all skeletons. After that, everything runs as expected.

If you need more instructions on how to set new Python interpreter: Pycharm has a [detailed instrucions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html).

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you would have to download the source files and build it yourself. Please note the statement on the statement on their site "Warning: PyPy3.5 is considered beta software". This tells me that it may be buggy at this moment.

Check out http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/release-pypy3-2.3.1.html?highlight=windows and you'll note support for windows 32 bit but not 64 bit, and that's in the historical information for the version of pypy3 2.3.1